# I want to denormalise two rows of two columns into 4 different columns with one row

Tags: mysql, pentaho, etl

Consider the following:

```
Before Processing
ID1  ID2  Type Cabin Tier Fee ED
2733 2606   43     4    2 100 4.77273
2733 2606   43     4    2 140 7.90909

After Processing
ID1  ID2  Type Cabin Tier Fee1 Fee2 ED1     ED2
2733 2606   43     4    2 100  140  4.77273 7.90909
```

Im using Pentaho ETL for my work.

The first step is the **Table input** where I'm taking all the unique set of data **ID1, ID2, Type, Cabin, Tier** with count of rows greater than 3 as required in my case.

Then I'm taking a  **Database join** to get data for one set of the above arguments wherein the two ED values are closest to 1 and their Fee values.

I need to further apply some calculations on the Fees and EDs and thought it would be easy to have them as Fee1 and Fee2 along with ED1 and ED2.

I tried using **Row Flattner** but I can only change one column data at a time. I want two row of columns **Fee** and **ED** to be flattened to 4 different columns as in the image "After Processing".

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you decide which fee is fee1?

Comment: Is a "Group by"-step possible?
Sort by ID1  ID2  Type Cabin Tier;
Group by ID1  ID2  Type Cabin Tier;
Seperate Fee & ED with ";"
Split Fields-Step (with ";" as the seperator...

Comment: I get the data sorted according to the lowest ED and limit total rows output to 2 so Fee1 will be the least corresponding to the lowest ED of the two and Fee2 will be the other value.  I did not get understand the ";" separator part.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, so as answer (hopefully helpful):

**Required:**
Your data should be like in your example (the first five fields are the same for a grouping):

Based on your starting position / before processing it should work by following these instructions.

Right after the Before-Processing-situation:

1. step: sort by (get the first 5 fields to sort for the following group by-step)
2. step: group by the first 5 fields (so except the Fee and ED, these two are to be setted in the Aggregates fields with "Concatenate strings separated by ,") --> ";" or "," its nearly the same here, but will be important on the next step
3. Preview: If you do a preview you get this:

ID1;ID2;Type;Cabin;Tier;Fee;ED

```
2733;2606;43;4;2;**100,140**;**4.77273,7.90909**
```

The grouped values Fee and ED are seperated with "," in one field.

4. Split fields-Steps:
   now it's time to split the fields Fee and ED (you will need two split fields steps for each one. The delimiter for splitting is "," here, you have to give a name for the second field in the split field-steps.

The last steps splits the fields and you have the values in one row for calculating as you want.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this. Thank u.

Comment: I tried **group by** and then **2 Split Fields** and it works but the Decimals in ED are rounded up. Like, if I have ED values of  **0.98616** and **1.02804**,  they are rounded up to 1. How to fix this issue?

Comment: For this you need a "select values step" after "split fields". In "Select-values" choose the Sheet "Meta-data", get the fields and choose the wanted fields.
Type should be Number, Format try this "#.#####" and set the Decimal-Symbol to "."

Comment: Got it. I Casted the ED values initially itself to CHAR and do group by and get the right decimals. Thank you.